# Pivot not give expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I m using pivot and unpivot but I dot get expected output

Here is my sample data set

> Table 1

```
id    c_code
-----------------
123     1
456     1
```

> Table 2

```
id   c_code   i_t_code   i_code  
----------------------
123     1     TWinc     10              
123     1     TBinc     20      
123     1     TSinc     30
```

> Table 3

```
i_code   i_t_code   i_name 
------------------------------
10        TWinc        abc         
20        TBinc        xyz
30        TSinc        pqr
```

Here is my query

> Query

```
select * from (
    select id,inc,i_t_code from (
        select a.id,b.i_name,cast(b.i_code AS                        
        VARCHAR(128)) as i_code,b.i_t_code
        from 
        table_1 a
        join 
        table_2 b 
        on a.id= b.id
        and 
        a.c_code = b.c_code 
        join
        tabl_3 c on c.i_code = b.i_code 
        and 
        c.i_t_code = b.i_t_code 

        on a.i_code = b.i_code 
) d 
Unpivot
(
 inc for details in (i_name,i_code)
) as unpt) as uppt_res
PIVOT
(
   max(inc)
   FOR [i_t_code] IN ([TWinc],[TBinc],[TSinc])
) AS P
```

> Expected output:

```
id        TWinc_n   TWinc_c  TBinc_n  TBinc_c   TSinc_n   TSinc_c
------------------------------------------------------------
123         abc       10       xyz     20        pqr      30
```

> Actual output:

```
 id         TWinc    TBinc   TSinc   
------------------------------------
123          abc      xyz     pqr
```

How can do this ??

It is possible using pivot or any other solution is there

can anyone help to fix this ?

Comment: Please show the data you are starting with.  And, ahem, MySQL does not support `pivot` as far as I know, so tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: TWinc   ,TWinc     how you have same column name

Comment: Starting data is very large, I have show result after unpivot , I want answer how to deal with same column name in pivot

Comment: You don't have to show the entire data set, but show the part of the data set that you expect to produce your target output.  And, as @ZaynulAbadinTuhin pointed out, having multiple columns with the same name is problematic - that's why SQL Server allows for column aliases.

Comment: Why do you want two columns with the same name?   How do you plan to consume this resultset?

Comment: @Brian, I Have mentioned sample data in my question

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to give your data some variation if you want to stop pivot from compressing equal data items together when it's converting row data into column names and picking the `max(inc)` - probably easiest to do by changing the contents of the unpivoted data, tacking on a row number:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   select stoneid, inc, CONCAT(inclusion_type_id, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY inclusion_type_id ORDER BY inc)) as inclusion_type_id FROM
   (
       select 
           a.stoneid,
           b.inclusion_name,
           cast(b.inclusion_code AS VARCHAR(128)) as     inclusion_code,
           b.inclusion_type_id,
           b.inclusion_type_code  
       from 
           PACKET.STONE_LAB_INCLUSIONS a
           inner join 
           MASTER.INCLUSION_MASTER b 
           on 
               a.inclusion_code = b.inclusion_code and 
               a.inclusion_type_code = b.inclusion_type_code

           inner join 
           packet.stone_details c 
           on 
               c.stoneid = a.stoneid  and 
               c.certificate_code = a.certificate_code 
   ) d 
   UNPIVOT(inc for details in (inclusion_name,inclusion_code)) as unpt
) uppt_res
PIVOT
(
   MAX(inc)
   FOR [inclusion_type_id] IN ([TWinc1],[TWinc2],[TBinc1],[TBinc2],[TSinc1],[TSinc2])
) AS P
```

If you're desperate to have column names the same, you can alias the results of this query rather than `select *`